# Hybris, ant clean all command failes with message Error occurred during initialization of VM

Tags: java, ant, sap-commerce-cloud, securitymanager

I'm getting this error while trying to build my Hybris project via ant clean all && ./hybrisserver.sh debug:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.Error: Could not create SecurityManager
    at java.lang.System.initPhase3(java.base@11.0.9.1/System.java:2065)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: allow
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@11.0.9.1/BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@11.0.9.1/ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@11.0.9.1/ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(java.base@11.0.9.1/Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(java.base@11.0.9.1/Class.java:398)
    at java.lang.System.initPhase3(java.base@11.0.9.1/System.java:2050)
```

Maybe I put a typo somewhere (see Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: allow
) but I can't find anything and my repo's up to date with master which is correctly working, Is there a way to find the problem?

Note: i have Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solution was simple:
Somehow I lost my setantenv.sh configuration, i had to re-run it in /platform